# Receiver not calling in Alarm Manager android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-permissions

Hi I need to use notification for particular date in android. So I used alarm manager to trigger in receiver. But Broadcast receiver is not calling. Here is my code.

Here is piece of code..

In Details activity:

```
Log.e("alarm set", "cal" + cal.getTime());
        setAlarm(cal);

  private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){
    //this log got printed.
    Log.e("alarm set",""+targetCal.getTime());

    Intent intent = new Intent(Details.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Details.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

But AlarmReceiver is not calling.

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    //this is not working.
    Log.e("alarm",";alarm");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);

}
```

}

I given permission as,

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />

    <service
        android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
```

I couldn't find what mistake I am doing.

Thanks in advance.